# What's wrong with such tools: texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-recommended latex-xcolor pgf latex-beamer prosper texlive tipa?

Tags: git, ubuntu, installation, apt-get

I tried to install 'git' at Ubuntu 9.4 development platform, using command:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

I got message as below. I seems the trouble starting from "fmtutil-sys failed". From near end of below message, it appears

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
texlive-latex-base
texlive-latex-recommended
...............
tipa
```

When I tried to install any of them (texlive-latex-base or texlive-latex-recommended, or .. tipa), I got the same error messages. It complains errors while processing such list of utilities.

I wonder how come such list of utilities are always complained causing errors, even I tried to install any one of them.

Anyone knows how I can do to complete 'git' installation.
Thanks.

```
-------- log of command line message -------
stan@yocto-2014-0618$ sudo apt-get install git-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
git-core is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up texlive-latex-base (2007.dfsg.1-5) ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... done.
Building format(s) --all --cnffile /etc/texmf/fmt.d/10texlive-latex-base.cnf.
    This may take some time... 
fmtutil-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/fmtutil.cwDYmWcq
Please include this file if you report a bug.

dpkg: error processing texlive-latex-base (--configure):
 subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive-latex-recommended:
 texlive-latex-recommended depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2007-11); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing texlive-latex-recommended (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-xcolor:
 latex-xcolor depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing latex-xcolor (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pgf:
 pgf depends on latex-xcolor (>= 2.00-1); however:
  Package latex-xcolor is not configured yet.
 pgf depends oNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                        No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                            No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                            n texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing pgf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of latex-beamer:
 latex-beamer depends on pgf (>= 1.00-1); however:
  Package pgf is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on latex-xcolor (>= 2.00-1); however:
  Package latex-xcolor is not configured yet.
 latex-beamer depends on texlive-latex-base | tetex-extra; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
  Package tetex-extra is not installed.
dpkg: error processing latex-beamer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of prosper:
 prosper depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
 prosper depends on texlive-latex-recommended; however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing prosper (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texlive:
 texlive depends on texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2007-11); however:
  Package texlive-latex-recommended is not configured yet.
 texlive depends on texlive-latex-base (>= 2007-11); however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing texlive (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tipa:
 tipa depends on texlive-latex-base; however:
  Package texlive-latex-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing tipa (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 texlive-latex-base
 texlive-latex-recommended
 latex-xcolor
 pgf
 latex-beamer
 prosper
 texlive
 tipa
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original issues happened on ubuntu 9.04. The issue came from trying to install 'git', which must be version 12.04 or above on ubuntu. I think that's the reason.
I upgraded my platform to ubuntu 14.04, it works fine.